# Error reporting in PHP withi '.ini' files

Tags: php, ini

So basically I have tried to setup an error reporting system that logs any PHP, HTML or any other error into a text file called 'errors.txt' located in a specific directory. However, the file is not being created.

Here is the code:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
ini_set('error_log','/xampp/xampp-portable-win32-1.8.3-2-VC11/xampp/htdocs/EstateAgent/logs/errors.txt');
ini_set('display_errors',FALSE);
```

The errors are still be displayed to the user and they error log isn't being created inside of the directory specified.

I have also tried changing the standard values in my 'php.ini' file as suggested on other websites and I have still had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you restart Apache (or whatever webserver you are using) after changing `php.ini`?

Comment: Yeah tried this multiple times still no luck... :/

Comment: Wait, did you use that syntax `ini_set()` _inside_ the php.ini file? That is a runtime function call to be used in PHP code.  In the `php.ini` file it should look like `error_reporting = E_ALL` or `log_errors = true`

Comment: No no, this code is inside of a PHP page for my website! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For anyone who has similar problem - make sure you don't have any other error_reporting and ini_set in other files you use in your project. In those cases it may seem that error reporting is not working properly but in fact it this.**

Try to change:

```
ini_set('log_errors',TRUE);
```

into

```
ini_set('log_errors','1');
```

and

```
ini_set('display_errors',FALSE);
```

into

```
ini_set('display_errors','0');
```

If it doesn't help, add at the very top beginning of your file:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    ini_set('display_errors','0');
    echo $testVariable;
    echo "Just testing"; 
?>
```

and check if any warning about this variable is displayed before "Just testing".

Now change above code into:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','1');
    echo $testVariable;
    echo "Just testing"; 
?>
```

and check if any warning about this variable id displayed before "Just testing".

As above 2 sample codes works as expacted, it's likely that those settings are change in other php files of user or php libraries used by user. You should scan your code and libraries code do track where changes are made and try to solve this issue either removing your code changing your desired reporting or commenting / setting properly (if there is such possibility in constructor or method) reporting in external library

Comment: Sadly this doesn't fix anything either. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: Try to change your log file to simple ini_set('error_log','errors.txt'); and look if it's created when any errors appear

Comment: What happen if you remove those line from question and set simple error_reporting(0) and ini_set('display_errors','0'); - are any errors visible to user ?

Comment: 'Parse error: syntax errors' are still being displayed to the user.

Comment: Ok, I think you should make 100% sure you are editing the correct file. If you add echo "Just testing"; at the same beginning of your file (just after <?php ), is it displayed at the same top of your page or some other texts/messages/warning are displayed before "Just testing"?

Comment: I am definitely editing the correct page and if I use the 'echo "Just testing";' piece of code it prints it out at the very top of the page as expected.

Comment: Ok. I've edited answer above. You can make those 2 more tests.

Comment: Ooo, so the first edit only displayed the two words 'Just testing', whereas the second edit displayed an actual error in front of the two words. :)

Comment: So it probably means that in this file or other files (I assume you have many files in your project) in some place there are lines with error_reporting or ini_set that change inital settings. You should search in our your files strings "error_reporting" and "ini_set" to know where the change is made. It you for example use external library they may change those settings so you either should change in this library their code (rather bad idea) or just after it change error reporting (for example in constructor) restoring behaviour you want

Comment: I ensured that all 'error_reporting(0);' pieces of code that I was using before had been removed like you said, restarted XAMPP and it works now! Thanks for your help :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a fullpath for the 'error_log' property:

```
<?php
ini_set('error_log', 'c:/xampp/logs/php_error.log');
?>
```

You need to make sure that the following folder exists and is "writable": c:/xampp/logs/

If you're using Linux, then the fullpath will look like this: /xampp/logs/php_error.log

Also, use the following:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', '1');
?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I had already tried adding a full path before, but still had no success and the other 'ini' code you provided also did not work. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: If it doesn't work with a fullpath, then most probably the "logs" folder you're using isn't writable. You have no privilege to create a file there (or the Apache User has no privilege to create a file there).

Comment: I thought that this could have been the problem but I used the 'is_writable()' function to check to see if that directory could be written to and it could! Thanks for your suggestion, it's working now anyway :P